# Change HP Printer default to A4 instead of Letter in Win10

Tags: windows-10, printer

If I check the Properties of my HP Deskjet Printer on the Windows 10 Laptop it shows the default paper size as "Letter" (screenshot below).

I tried changing the setting under "Advanced Options" to A4. But still the main properties page shows the paper size as "Letter". Is there somewhere else to change this?

Context: The printer seems to often think that it is out of paper (orange blinking light) when in fact the feed tray is full (of A4 paper). I am wondering whether this mismatch is the reason.

PS. Checked the HP Smart app and even there the paper settings reflect A4 correctly. Screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: All the settings for A4 Paper Default appear to be via the Windows App settings. Perhaps try resetting the Printer to its default settings and try again.  https://123-hp-com.com/factory-reset-hp-deskjet-3630/

Comment: THanks @John. I have posted a screenshot of the App. And even there the paper settings seem correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

According to the HP 3630 Manual, the default paper size can be changed.

You might wish to first set the printer to default settings. This will also reset wireless, so you can try the paper settings below without resetting, and then if necessary reset the printer and try again.

**HP DeskJet 3630 Factory Reset to Factory Default State**

> 1. Turn Printer On.  Press and quickly release the Power button.
> 2. Wait for Printer to Finish Starting Up. Power up finishes when all printer noise stops, and the Power button glows steady white after the
>    3630 boots.
> 3. Next, Press and Hold the Power Button. Don’t release it though, until you run the next two steps.
> 4. Then, Quickly Press and Release the Start Copy Black Button Twice.  While holding in the Power button, also press and release Start Copy.
> 5. Wait for WiFi Network Status Light to Blink White.  The light is located as shown in the next picture. When it blinks, the 3630 deletes
>    the old information from its memory. Then, it’s ready for programming
>    with new wireless network details.
> 6. Complete.

Go to the 3630 Manual:

http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04649694

Then on Page 19:

**Change the default paper size detected by printer**

> The printer can automatically detect whether the input tray has paper
> loaded and detect whether the loaded paper is large, small, or medium
> width.
>
> You can change the default large, medium, or small paper size detected
> by the printer.
>
> To change the default paper size detected by the printer.
>
> 1. Open the embedded web server (EWS). For more information, see Open the embedded web server on page 76.
> 2. Click the Settings tab.
> 3. In the Preferences section, click Tray and Paper  management, and then select the desired option.
> 4. Click Apply.

Good luck with this.